# Conditional Printing for Front and Back page

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using iReport 5.2.0 and I have 2 reports that I want to print.
Both reports contain dynamic data and can be of multiple pages. However, number of pages of first report is always equal to number of pages in second report.

In my current setup, the first report is always printed completely and then all the pages of the second report are printed.

However, my requirement is that the report should print in the following sequence:

- Page 1 of Report 1.
- Page 1 of Report 2.
- Page 2 of Report 1.
- Page 2 of Report 2.
- Page 3 of Report 1.
- Page 3 of Report 2.
- ...

Is there any way I could achieve this with JasperReports?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post both of your jrxml in order to give better solution. is both jrxml uses the same datasource ?

Comment: @FahadAnjum : The data source is same for both the reports. I did not post the jrxml as they are very complex. Moreover, both of them are working fine independently. It's just the printing sequence that I need to set.

Comment: You can switch pages after you have filled the reports. Ping me if you like to know more

Answer (score 0):

Lets say , report 1 uses X query with X_SQL and  report 2 uses Y query with Y_SQL.

If both of the query has same number of column then it is great otherwise   add additional column with respect to X_SQL and Y_SQL in order to union both query.

Remember you have to generate one number series column and one dummy column in your sql. You can generate number series dynamically in your sql.

X_SQL with two new column (number_series,'detail1'as dummy)
union 
Y_SQL with two new column (number_series,'detail2'as dummy)
order by number_series, dummy

OUTPUT of SQL:

X_SQL column , 1 as number_series, 'detail1' as dummy
Y_SQL column , 1 as number_series, 'detail2' as dummy
X_SQL column , 2 as number_series, 'detail1' as dummy
Y_SQL column , 2 as number_series, 'detail2' as dummy

Now add two detail band in your new report. Height of report is only one detail band height + top and bottom padding.

1 detail band = first report design
2 detail band = second report design

U can use subreport if your jrxml is too complex.

Now in print when expression of detail band use

detail band 1 : $F{dummy}.equals('detail1')
detail band 2 : $F{dummy}.equals('detail2')

Note: 
1) you need to order by in your sql query.
2) height of report need to choose properly.

If still you are having issue then i suggest to post your jrxml.